# only have 6gb of storage of 500gb after installing with unetbootin

Tags: dual-boot, unetbootin

So basically I was trying to switch from windows 10 to Ubuntu, set up unetbootin, got into the trial version of Ubuntu. Then I started the install process. When I got to the part where you partition the disk I think I messed up, because now windows won't boot even from recovery and in Ubuntu it says I only have 6 GB of local storage with the rest used up, which is in no way possible. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: you said you used unetbootin to get into Ubuntu.  What did unetbootin write to?  USB or CD/DVD?  It can't write directly to system partitions for installs.  And unetbootin is considered 'deprecated' in favor of Rufus or Etcher.

Comment: Idk, it did install on my hdd directly

Answer (score 0):

1- Do you already remove the installation media or other media (flash drive or cd)? An volume with 6gb seems to me be the size of a media that was unintentionally chosen to boot at installation.

2- If this is not the first case, you would need to know more about system to help. To this, open a terminal with `ctrl + alt + t` and run the command `fdisk -l` which will list all media on the computer.

Sorry for my english, I used the internet translator

Comment: So, I didn't use a USB drive or anything to install, just partitioned the drive but what I think happened is that Ubuntu installed on my system boot partition and not the one I had made. Now Ubuntu won't even boot

Comment: @NotaPowVirgin, please clarify that comment. You did use something to install. Also, your original question suggests that Ubuntu does boot.

Comment: So I partitioned my drive in to 3 parts, one for windows(~200gb), one for system boot(~6gb) and one for Ubuntu(~200gb) I then put the Ubuntu iso on the Ubuntu partition and Unetbootin. Restarted computer gives unetbootin option, load into trail version and start Ubuntu install. Then goes to the partitioning for Ubuntu, I clear the windows partition and make one big partition for Ubuntu, and still have the system boot partition, then start the install, everything goes fine but when done says drive is full execpt 6gb.

Comment: . Then I go into recovery mode try to clean things out and now it won't give a UI I think because there is no space to install Nvidia drivers, that's what it says in root terminal from recovery mode